# Problem with Autocomplete (Material UI + React + Reagent/ClojureScript)

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, clojurescript, reagent-forms

I have a problem using the Material UI's `Autocomplete` with Reagent (ClojureScript). The element renders fine, but when I try to click on it, I get the following exceptions:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null
    at handleClick (useAutocomplete.js:938)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:189)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackImpl (react-dom.development.js:238)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:293)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:307)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:390)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:412)
    at forEachAccumulated (react-dom.development.js:3260)
    at runEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:3305)
    at handleTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:3515)

useAutocomplete.js:322 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of null
    at eval (useAutocomplete.js:322)
    at eval (useEventCallback.js:26)
    at eval (useAutocomplete.js:433)
    at eval (useEventCallback.js:26)
    at eval (useAutocomplete.js:463)
    at eval (useAutocomplete.js:528)
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:19765)
    at commitPassiveHookEffects (react-dom.development.js:19803)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:189)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackImpl (react-dom.development.js:238)
```

Breaking in JS debugger, I see that `inputRef.current` is null (which is what `focus` and `removeAttribute` are called on. (Oddly enough, the only place where `inputRef` is set in the file is by calling `useRef(null)`, which is what results in `inputRef.current` being null.)

In my code, I define the Autocomplete field as follows:

```
(ns my-product-redacted.views.atoms
  (:require [reagent.core :as r]
            ["@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete" :default Autocomplete]
            ;; other requires
  ))

(def autocomplete-field (r/adapt-react-class Autocomplete))
```

Then, in a React component, it is used as follows:

```
[a/autocomplete-field {:render-input      (fn [js-params]
                                            (let [clj-params (js->clj js-params)
                                                  params     {:label             label
                                                              :width             width
                                                              :select            select?
                                                              :Input-label-props {:shrink true}
                                                              :Select-props      {:native true}}
                                                  all-params  (into clj-params params)]
                                               (js/console.log (clj->js all-params))
                                               (r/as-element [a/text-field all-params])))
                       :options          (when select? (cons {:value "" :label ""} options))
                       :get-option-label (fn [option] (or (get (js->clj option) "label") ""))
                       :default-value    (when (not select?) value-override)
                       :value            (when select? value)
                       :disabled         disabled?
                       :on-focus         #(re-frame/dispatch [::forms/on-focus path])
                       :on-blur          #(re-frame/dispatch [::forms/on-blur path])
                       :on-change        #(re-frame/dispatch (conj on-change (-> % .-target .-value)))})]
```

(Here, `a/text-field` is also defined in the same namespace as `a/autocomplete-field` and in a similar way.)

The JS console log (from the `(js/console.log (clj->js params))` call) shows that `inputProps.ref.current` is set to null. However, `InputProps.ref` is not null. Even so, I tried to manually associate the same function as is passed with `InputProps.ref` to `inputProps.ref.current`, but that made no difference.

I have also tried the workaround suggested in https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/21245 (although that issue is with the Gestalt library, not with Reagent, it suggests that there may be a problem with ref forwarding). But wrapping the `text-field` into a div with the `ref` taken from `InputProps.ref` also made no difference.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling `js->clj` on the render-input js params breaks them.

I put a quick demo of the material UI autocomplete component in my demo repository [here](https://github.com/dakra/mui-templates/blob/master/src/mui_templates/views/components.cljs#L55-L58).

But it's mainly taken from the official reagent docs/examples [here](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/blob/e70c52531341bba83636e88eb7b60ff5796195b1/examples/material-ui/src/example/core.cljs#L78-L93):

```clj
(defn autocomplete-example []
  [:> mui/Grid
   {:item true}
   [:> Autocomplete {:options ["foo" "bar" "foobar"]
                     :style {:width 300}
                     ;; Note that the function parameter is a JS Object!
                     ;; Autocomplete expects the renderInput value to be function
                     ;; returning React elements, not a component!
                     ;; So reactify-component won't work here.
                     :render-input (fn [^js params]
                                     ;; Don't call js->clj because that would recursively
                                     ;; convert all JS objects (e.g. React ref objects)
                                     ;; to Cljs maps, which breaks them, even when converted back to JS.
                                     ;; Best thing is to use r/create-element and
                                     ;; pass the JS params to it.
                                     ;; If necessary, use JS interop to modify params.
                                     (set! (.-variant params) "outlined")
                                     (set! (.-label params) "Autocomplete")
                                     (r/create-element mui/TextField params))}]])
```